# MYSQL - copy one column to another in the same table - with conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a problem.

I want to copy values from column "guid" to "post content"

All rows are in one table "wp-posts"

One row in column "post parent" have a value and another item have this same value in column "ID"

The thing i must done is to

1. compare items id to post_parent and then
2. copy data from column "guid" which has "post parent" value (also not delete them from there) to "post_content" which has this same ID(add data to existed data at the top (not delete the also)

structure table wp_post

> **ID ||||| post_parent | guid ||||||||||||||||||| post_content |**
>
> 123 |||| 0 |||||||||||||||||||||||||| some data |||||||||||||| some content
>
> 5433 | 123 ||||||||||||||||||||| DATA TO COPY |  some content

I want to achive this:

> **ID |||||| post_parent | guid ||||||||||||||||||| post_content |**
>
> 123 |||||| 0 |||||||||||||||||||||||||| some data ||||||||||||| **DATA TO COPY** some content
>
> 5433 ||| 123 |||||||||||||||||||| DATA TO COPY |  some content

mysqlnd 5.0.8
Please help me, 
thank You for support

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed the bullets for you.  Please show is what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the requirement correctly, you need to join the parent to the children in the same table (`wp_posts` to `wp_posts`). You would then use something like this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts parent
    JOIN wp_posts child
    ON parent.id = child.post_parent 
SET parent.post_content = concat(child.guid, parent.post_content)
```

Note that by its nature, this can only work for a single child. If you have more than one child for a given post it will just take the first child but I don't know that this behaviour is specified and is probably not something you want to rely on.